# Application refused to start because of local storage

Tags: applications, crash, database

I am using application TopTracker on my MBP

My Mac have frozen and i have forced it to restart.

Unfortunatelly, when i'm trying to restart the App, i have this error :

> Failed to read from local storage. Database error:  Driver error:  The
>   application will now exit.

[image]

There is any way to reset this database?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the local storage, i have to go in

```
Library/Application Support/TopTracker
```

and delete

> TopTracker.db

This have fix my issue